# Was Soos inspired by Hurley?

Tags: inspiration, lost, character-similarity, gravity-falls

### Some minor *Gravity Falls* and *LOST* spoilers below.

Soos from *Gravity Falls* and Hurley from *LOST* have a remarkable number of similarities.

- Both are fair-skinned Americans of Hispanic descent.
- Both go by nicknames (Hugo "Hurley" Reyes and Jesus "Soos" Ramírez)
- Both are overweight.
- Both have brown hair and scraggily half-beards.
- Hurley was abandoned by his father during childhood and raised by his mother, a short, more obviously Hispanic woman. Soos was abandoned by his father during childhood and raised by his grandmother, a short, more obviously Hispanic woman.
- Both are Catholic.
- Both dress similarly.
- Both are not traditionally smart and serve as the "asks questions for the audience's benefit" character.
- Both are reoccurring characters on a science fiction/fantasy series with ongoing mysteries and frequent easter eggs and references.

Have any of the creators of *Gravity Falls* commented on the similarities between the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely.  Alex Hirsch, creator of Gravity Falls, has stated that his inspiration for Soos was a friend of his from college, Jesus Chambrot (pronounced Hey-Zeus, and, went by "Soos" for short).  He even posted a [picture on twitter](https://twitter.com/_alexhirsch/status/371810877617369089) where the guy looks remarkably like Soos.  Certain other aspects, like his last name, were taken from other sources, such as people on staff).

As for whether some similarities may have been drawn from Hurley, while it's certainly possible, there don't seem to be any evident signs.  Some of the similarities seem to be down to simple statistical correlations (according to a 2013 poll, over 50% of Hispanics identify as Catholic) and perhaps a few outright stereotypes (not necessarily deliberately or meant with hostile intent).

Presumably the character being somewhat "stupid" was exaggeration for comic effect.

Some of the other major characters seem to have been at least in part based on important people in Alex Hirsch's life, most notably Mabel is based on his actual twin sister (and Dipper on himself), and he's posted pictures of a relative who looked much like Grunkle Stan.